# Xpages xe:dialog rendered outside of form tags in domino 9.0.1 FP8

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I thought that the xe:dialog in 9.0.1 FP8 should be rendered inside the FORM tags ?  Is this not true.  Or is there something wrong with configuration/Setup on my Domino server and Extension Library ?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo requires dialogs to be outside the Form tag. What the Extension Library component does is ensure the content gets posted back to the server. Before XPages some manual post-processing had to be done to handle that. To my knowledge, nothing has changed with how the dialog works in Ext Lib. But Blame in the GitHub source would confirm that.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the clarification on this.  What prompted this question is I'm trying to execute a Java Bean which use the httpservletresponse from the FacesContext.  But I'm able to get the OutputStream correct when executed from a dialog.  The bean works correctly if ran from just a xpage.

Comment: HttpServletResponse is for a full XPage. Dialog content is populated via a partial refresh and injected into the DOM. That's likely to be the key difference.